# Ubuntu stuck in fallback after attempting to install cinnamon

Tags: ppa, data-recovery, cinnamon, purge

Running Ubuntu 14.03 dual booting along Windows 7. I have about 64gb of source code I really don't want to have to download again. So I installed the cinnamon PPA like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

But I forgot to add the mint repository before hand. Long story Ubuntu got stuck in *fallback* mode. So being a newb I did this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove cinnamon
```

My thought process was that I would remove cinnamon and the default desktop environment would be still there. So I guess is there any way to reinstall desktop environment or fix this **without** reformatting and starting over? I humbling call myself and newb and ask your guys' advice. Thanks in advance !

*****EDIT***** It also needs to be noted that I can't connect to WIFI, either the drivers aren't coming up or I just don't know the correct way to bring them "up." My computer also doesn't have an Ethernet or DVD drive, so its a wireless card and usb only. The machine boots up until the lock screen, then it errors out if you try to log in. Thanks again!

Comment: There is an Ubuntu mate 14.04  iso if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reply as comment because I don't have enough reputation so I'm going ahead and answer, just giving you some options to try, that I hope will be useful.

First, you will need some way to download from the net. Since you are asking here I assume you have that.

From your problem PC press `Ctrl-Alt-F1`, login and type:

```
apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq unity ubuntu-desktop
```

Hopefully, you will get the URIS of the packages you need, that you can download elsewhere and transfer via USB to your problem PC. I'll post the ones that I got:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-desktop_1.325_i386.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/unity_7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1_i386.deb

Let's say you copied them to your home folder, then (as before) from the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-desktop*.deb unity*.deb
```

EDITED: I added you need to change runlevel.

Comment: Lets give it a try.. One sec.

Comment: This is good, it is what I was going to suggest but why link to 32bit packages???

Comment: Ok, I got your point I should remove the links. But I'll leave them for now, just in case they prove to be useful for him.

Comment: @Chris: Just in case, what's the output of `nmcli nm status`?

Comment: I wasnt able to get it to work before I had to go to work. I'll try in a few hours when I get back home. I was getting dependency errors when running the dpkg .

Comment: Ok I took a peek at that networkmanager.. Something funky is going on with the drivers or something cuz bith the Wi-Fi card wlan0 and wlan1 the built in Wi-Fi are showing disconnected and I'm not able to the bring them up. Running a lsusb it shows the full name of the card and what port it's plugged into so I don't think it's on the USB side of things if that makes any sense.